# What are the means you use to monitor voice quality in your network?

Tags: monitoring, asterisk

What software/product do you use to monitor voice quality in your system? Do you use Asterisk manager API for making calls and recording audio? Do you have software to receive quality scores?

Answer (score 1):

Measuring quality in a call stream isn't the easiest thing to do. Our Sonus switches provide media quality info built in so we use that.  However we use a number of tools to measure network quality / SIP server responsiveness but one of the best tools I've found is to use smokeping (http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) with the SIP Ping probe to measure SIP packet latency and packet loss on the SIP servers.  It also measures latency and packet loss using ICMP and many other probes.  While it might not be the best to measure per call voice quality its pretty good at giving you a health state of your network.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SIP-ALG on your hardware device most of them support quality monitoring.  We use OnSip, Adtran Router, with SIP-ALG enabled, and it's built in VQM (Voice Quality Monitoring) - The SIPALG itself monitors all SIP-Events so that's really useful for debugging SIP problems as well.